# How do I get only the records between the specified period of time in MYSQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I get only the records between the specified period of time in mysql database using PHP?

My code is  this;

`$records= "SELECT * FROM contact_us WHERE \'submit_date(date(\"H:i:s\"))\' between \'16:00:00\' and \'08:00:00\'";`

Answer (score 1):

use the time functions from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

```
SELECT * FROM contact_us WHERE HOUR(submit_date) >= 16 AND HOUR(submit_date)<= 8
```

Comment: This worked for me to only grab a block of time of 2 hours like "(HOUR(r.r_timestamp) >= HOUR(TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))) AND (HOUR(r.r_timestamp) <= HOUR(TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))))" but I'm curious if this isn't optimized for the index of the r_timestamp since it's not ordered by hour in the first place.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM contact_us WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),attributename,108) between '16:00:00' and '08:00:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$records= "SELECT * FROM contact_us WHERE submit_date between '2012-11-01' and '2012-11-01'";
```

and take your datatype for that column as **datetime**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM contact_us WHERE
HOUR(submit_date) between 8 and 16;
```